# deliver content to the app from internet source

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Maybe this is not the correct place to ask this. But I didnt find any useful information in the way I searched.

I am making an app from jquery mobile and phonegap that has a html page that gets updated from a server.

I am new to this and where can I host the files on internet. Can I deliver content from a private dropbox like account. How secure are they. If I deliver content from an account like drpbox will it be a problem to get the app aproved from the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can deliver content straight from Dropbox via a public link. However, that content would be subject to Dropbox's terms of service - Dropbox can disable your link if you have a lot of people downloading it. A better alternative would be Amazon S3 or something similar. The appstore doesn't know where your app downloads content from, so that will not be affected in either case.